# Find an item in a dictionary value, in another dictionary value with a length of 1

Tags: python, dictionary

For every item in dictionary value with a len > 1, I am searching for that item in another dictionary value with a len == 1. If I find that item in another dictionary value with a len == 1, I want to remove it from the longer value. Example:

```
d = { 
    'key1' : ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    'key2' : ['one'],
    'key3' : ['two', 'three'],
    }
```

should return

```
{
 'key1' : ['two', 'three'],
 'key2' : ['one'],
 'key3' : ['two', 'three'],
}
```

my current code for this

```
allvals = match.values()

for k, v in match.iteritems():

    dontuse = []
    newval = []

    for i in v:
        for x in allvals:
            if x == v:
                pass
            elif i in x:
                if len(x) == 1:
                    dontuse.append(i)
    for i in v:
        if i in dontuse:
            pass
        else:
            newval.append(i)

    match[k] = list(set(newval))
```

However this is an extreme bottleneck with processing time. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does your solution work?

Comment: My solution works, it's just incredible slow when working with a large dictionary (potential 100,000+ keys).

Comment: In your output, should `dict[key2]` be `['one']` or `[]`?

Comment: dict[key2] should be ['one'] and 'one' should be removed from dict[key1]

Answer (score 1):

You only need to iterate through the dictionary once to find `dontuse`. Then you just copy the dictionary over, leaving out list entries as needed for lists of length greater than 1. A couple of list and dictionary comprehensions give a concise solution:

```
dontuse = {s for val in match.values() for s in val if len(val) == 1}
match = {key: [s for s in val if len(val) == 1 or not s in dontuse] for key, val in match.iteritems()}
```

Also, it's better not to use `dict` or any other built-in as a variable name.

Comment: better to use a `set()` for `dontuse`, lookup in a set is `O(1)` vs `O(n)` for list.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, never even crossed my mind to iterate through once to find dontuse first. Both of your solutions are perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to interpret what you are trying to do but I believe you can break it into 2 steps:

- create a set of items to remove
- remove items for lists len > 1

Both of these can be done with comprehensions (set, dict), e.g.:

```
>>> d = { 'key1' : ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'key2' : ['one'], 'key3' : ['two', 'three']}
>>> r = {v[0] for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == 1}
>>> {k: [v for v in vs if v not in r] if len(vs) > 1 else vs for k, vs in d.items()}
{'key1': ['two', 'three'], 'key2': ['one'], 'key3': ['two', 'three']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is using sets:

```
match = { 1 : ['one', 'two', 'three'], 2 : ['one'], 3 : ['two', 'three'] }

singles=set()
for v in match.values():
    if len(v)==1:
        singles.add(v[0])


for k, v in match.iteritems():
    if len(v)>1:
        for el in v:
            if el in singles:
                match[k].remove(el)

match
{1: ['two', 'three'], 2: ['one'], 3: ['two', 'three']}
```